# Build JSON request body for Apex REST POST API Callout using JSONGenerator class. This is my first Apex REST API so need help to build JSON body

Tags: rest-api

**json2Apex Class**

```
public class processingObj {
    public class processReq {
        public String applId;
        public String DOB;
        public businessAppl businessAppl;
        public List<coApplList> coApplList;
        public String Name;
        public Address homeAddress;
        public String mobilePhone;
    }
    
    public class businessAppl {
        public Address busaddress;
        public String applId;
        public String DOB;
        public String businessName;
        public Address mailAddress;
        public String phone;
    }

    public class Address {
        public String address;
        public String city;
        public String state;
    }

    public class coApplList {
        public Address address;
        public String applicantId;
        public String applId;
        public String Name;
    }
}
```

**Payload to build JSON body for POST method**

```
{
  "applId": "string",
  "DOB": "2021-09-23",
  "businessAppl": {
    "busaddress": {
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string"
    },
    "applId": "string",
    "DOB": "2021-09-23",
    "businessName": "string",
    "mailAddress": {
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string"
    },
    "phone": "string"
  },
  "coApplList": [
    {
      "address": {
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string"
      },
      "applicantId": "string",
      "applId": "string",
      "Name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "Name": "string",
  "homeAddress": {
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "state": "string"
  },
  "mobilePhone": "string"
}
```

[![json pay load][1]][1]

**Here is my API Callout to POST above payload**

```
public class processingApplication {
    public static void reprocessingApplication(string applId, processingObj.processReq process){
        Integer responseCode;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        
        request.setEndpoint('callout:tstApi/api/');
        
        request.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

        String accessToken = retrieveToken();
        request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);

        request.setMethod('POST');

        String jsonBody = buildJSON(process);        
        request.setBody(jsonBody);
        system.debug('FILE REQ BODY**'+request.getBody());
        system.debug('FILE REQ EP**'+request.getEndpoint());
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        system.debug('FILE RES BODY**'+response.getBody());
    }
    
   
    private static string buildJSON(processingObj.processReq apexObj){
        String JSONdata = '';
        
        if(apexObj != null){
            JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
            gen.writeStartObject();     
            gen.writeStringField('applId', apexObj.applId);
            gen.writeStringField('DOB', apexObj.DOB);
                gen.writeStartObject();
                gen.writeObjectField('businessAppl', apexObj.businessAppl); 
                gen.writeEndObject();
                //Stuck here for busaddress
            gen.writeStartArray();
            //Stuck here for coApplList
            gen.writeEndArray();
            gen.writeEndObject();
            jsonData = gen.getAsString();
            System.debug('jsonData-' + jsonData);
        }
        return JSONdata;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to build JSON request body for Apex REST POST API Callout using JSONGenerator class. I tried building it in my class processingApplicationbut got stuck at building inner part of json payload for businessAppl and coApplList

Comment: First you need to create the object structure then use json.serilize () and request.setbody explore other json menthod if you want strict validation or removing null values from request

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty This is my first REST API callout could you please give one sample example

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288573/how-to-pass-json-in-set-body-using-rest-and-method-post-in-apex

Comment: Thanks @AvijitChakraborty but i am looking for generate json body using JSONGenerator class