# How to frame a Nested JSON Payload in HTTP Post request Body in Apex.?

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, json, apex-webservice

I wanted to frame a Nested JSON Payload as below into HTTP Post request Body in Apex and send it to external system.

```
{
   "product": "Protocol products",
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard",
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "protocol 1",
        "value": "Prt1"
      },
      {
        "name": "protocol 2",
        "value": "prt2"
      },
      {
        "name": "protocol 3",
        "value": "prt3"
      }
    ]
}
```

Although the answers here [How to pass JSON in Set.Body Using rest and method= Post in apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288573/how-to-pass-json-in-set-body-using-rest-and-method-post-in-apex?newreg=8fb76358e2d844f99f7c22b640bbcd49) are helpful to an extent, I couldn't get the params part of JSON to working, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have two classes:

```
public class NameValuePair {
  public String name, value;
  public NameValuePair(String name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
public class ProductData {
  public String product, title, vendor, product_type;
  public List<NameValuePair> params = new List<NameValuePair>();
}
```

Which you can then construct:

```
ProductData data = new ProductData();
data.product = 'Protocol products';
data.title = 'Burton Custom Freestyle 151';
data.vendor = 'Burton';
data.product_type = 'Snowboard';
data.params.add(new NameValuePair('protocol 1', 'Prt1'));
data.params.add(new NameValuePair('protocol 2', 'prt2'));
data.params.add(new NameValuePair('protocol 3', 'prt3'));
```

Then serialize your data when you're done:

```
String jsonPayload = JSON.serialize(data);
```

In the future, you can also use https://json2apex.herokuapp.com to generate some sample code you can start from. This takes a lot of the guesswork out of writing these classes.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The solution worked.